# Tomcat, JAX-WS, Hibernate - flaws and solutions?

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, tomcat, jaxb

I am currently working on a client (java/swing) server (tomcat/hibernate/jax-ws) application that requires many database operations and should be able to execute long-running background tasks on the server-side. I chose this setup mainly for a better code reuse.

However, there are some issues that, probably, many others have also faced and found solutions for:

One of the biggest issues was lazy-loading vs. jax-ws. There were some viable solutions like overriding the jax-ws accessors ([JAX-WS + Hibernate + JAXB: How to avoid LazyInitializationException during marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509921/jax-ws-hibernate-jaxb-how-to-avoid-lazyinitializationexception-during-marsh)) that solved this issue be replacing the hibernate's proxies with null.

Now I'm facing new problems described by this example:

An entity "customer" is located within a "country", thus: n:1 relationship.

The "country" within the "customer" is marked as lazy-loaded to avoid unnecessary database traffic. When the client UI wants to list customers (the country is not needed here), the country-proxy is replaced by null within the jax-ws accessor and everything is fine.
When editing a customer, however, (I think) I must join the country, even when not viewing/changing it. Otherwise its proxy would be replaced by null when sent to the client via jax-ws, then sent back to the server, and committed (with null) into the database. Hereafter my customer->country association is lost.

Maybe there are several solutions like:

- marking the country as "optional=false" triggering an exception when I forgot to join the country beforehand and then try to save the customer. Using this approach I must always join all references even when they are not part of the editing process. References requiring "optional=true" would pass silently and coding mistakes might destroy the database.
- not replacing the proxy by null within the jax-ws accessor, but some other dummy class that, when sent back from the client to the server, is replaced by the original proxy. But I'm not sure whether this is feasible at all.
- use hibernate within the client and connect directly to the database, using jax-ws only for non-database interaction
- write some code to allow lazy-loading within the client (when necessary) by sending corresponding jax-ws requests (couldn't find the StackOverflow link anymore where someone asked for something like this). Totally feels like reinventing hibernate...

Are there any other solutions, recommendations, best-practices, better setups for this kind of application?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is not restricted to your "JAX-WS to Hibernate" scenario. Also in other szenarios you will face this "null-value" problem.

One solution is the "DIY merge pattern":

1. Send the entity from client to server.
2. On the server invoke "EntityManager.find" with the received ID to find the existing entity.
3. Now copy over the state ourselves. If EntityManager.find returns null, its new -> just persist the received object.

Example:

```
Customer serverCustomer = dao.findById(receivedCustomer.getId());
if(serverCustomer == null) {
    dao.persist(clientCustomer);
} else {
    serverCustomer.setName(receivedCustomer.getName());
    serverCustomer.setDate(receivedCustomer.getDate());
    // ... all other fields, except "Country"
    if (receivedCustomer.getCountry() != null) {
       // Country keeps its server state if no new data
       serverCustomer.setDate(receivedCustomer.getCountry());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very specific solution and is only feasible in case I do not need to change the reference at all. In some cases, however, I must be able to change it and "null" might even be a valid reference (optional references). There must be some sort of noticeable difference between "null - due to: coder forgot to join" and "null - due to: we really want null here"

Comment: If you just need the abilitiy to change with new data, you have no problem... see updated answere. You HAVE in fact a problem if you need the abilitiy to delete a customer <-> country relation.Than you need additional information.
I would suggest to define a transport-object with your customer as "payload" and some addition infos about it. Like a list with fields to remove.

Comment: that was the approach of my second bullet point. distinguishing between "null: update" and "missing: do not update". I am searching for a solution, not having to write several custom merges for each entity and its use-case. can't believe large systems rely on thousands of lines of manual-merge code. There must be something else.. I guess just using (un)marshalling proxy->XYZ and XYZ->proxy (instead of just "null") would suffice for my use-case. But I'm not sure whether hibernate supports creating a proxy on my own...

Answer (score 0):

You apparently store data differently compared to how you transfer it. So it might make sense NOT to use the same object instances for transfer and for storage.

One of the solutions is to used different classes for that - DTOs and entities. You store entities but transfer DTOs. This takes additional effort to implement DTOs and mapping DTOs<->entities but this gives you clear separation of layers and may be even more efficient (from the effort point of view) in the long run. You can use Dozer and likes for mapping between DTOs an entities.

Another approach is to use not different classes but different instances of objects for transfer and storage. This is probably similar to @VinZ answer. You "merge" data from source object into the target object. I wrote a [JAXB plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins) to generate such merge methods some time ago and found the approache very useful in different use cases.
With this approach you save significant amount of effort compared to DTOs, but don't have a layer separation on the class level.

I personally would go with well-developed and polished structure of entities and extra DTOs optimized for transfer. I'd also try to autogenerate the merge/copy methods somehow to avoid the need of writing the manually. A JAXB plugin maybe. I love writing JAXB plugins so if something can be solved with a JAXB plugin, I'd solve it with a JAXB plugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The difference results only from not being able to lazy-load references on the client side and thus having to use workarounds as proxy->null. Using DTOs would probably result in many different classes depending on each use case for the customer entity. Furthermore I already have equals(), hashCode(), validate() etc. methods for all Entities to use them within the UI. Currently it feels like using Hibernate directly within the Client might be the best choice? However this lacks the additional security layer enforced by the server...

Comment: when using DTOs, how would one transfer references (like Country) and then persist a change within Customer on the server side? Like: Use an attribute "countryID" for the reference or a complete CountryDTO? Does the Server have to query the Country entity by this ID first and then assign it to Customer or is it possible to set the Customer's Country-reference directly just using the ID?